Analytic continuation of $\sin(\pi x)\cdot\text{PV}\int_0^1\frac{s^{x-1}}{s+t}\mathrm{d}s$, for $t\in(0,1]$
Introduction
I want to write the function
$$x!_{(\infty)}=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}k^{\text{sinc}(x-k)}\qquad\text{where}\;\;\text{sinc}(x):=\begin{cases}
\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}&x\neq 0\\
1&x=0
\end{cases} $$
in terms of integral only for all $x$.

Step 1.1:
\begin{align*}x!_{(\infty)}=&\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}k^{\text{sinc}(x-k)}\\
=&\exp\left(\ln\left(\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}k^{\text{sinc}(x-k)}\right)\right)\\
=&\exp\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(\pi(x-k)\right)}{\pi(x-k)}\ln(k)\right)\\
=&\exp\left(\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{x-k}\ln(k)\right)
\end{align*}
Step 1.2: Now I calculate only the series
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{x-k}\ln(k)=&-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{k^{n+1}}\ln(k)\\
=&-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k^{n+1}}\ln(k)
\end{align*}
Step 1.3: Now I calculate the series over $k$
\begin{align*}
-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k^{n+1}}\ln(k)=&\frac{\partial}{\partial n}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k^{n+1}}\\
=&-\frac{\partial}{\partial n}\eta(n+1)\\
=&-\eta'(n+1)
\end{align*}
Step 1.4: I use the integral representation of $\eta$ function
$$\eta(z)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{z-1}}{e^t+1}\mathrm{d}t$$
So the derivative is
$$\eta'(z)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{z-1}\left(\ln(t)-\psi(z)\right)}{e^{t}+1}\mathrm{d}t$$
Step 1.5: I return to the previous series
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{x-k}\ln(k)=&-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k^{n+1}}\ln(k)\\
=&-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\eta'(n+1)x^n\\
=&-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\Gamma(n+1)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{n}\left(\ln(t)-\psi(n+1)\right)}{e^{t}+1}\mathrm{d}t x^n\\
&-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{e^{t}+1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(tx\right)^{n}}{n!}\left(\ln(t)-\psi(n+1)\right)\mathrm{d}t\\
=&\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{e^{t}+1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(tx\right)^{n}}{n!}\psi(n+1)\mathrm{d}t-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(t)}{e^{t}+1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(tx\right)^{n}}{n!}\mathrm{d}t\\
=&\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{tx}\left(\ln(|tx|)-\text{Ei}(-tx)\right)}{e^{t}+1}\mathrm{d}t-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(t)e^{tx}}{e^{t}+1}\mathrm{d}t\\
=&\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{tx}(\ln(|x|)-\text{Ei}(-tx))}{e^{t}+1}\mathrm{d}t\\
&-t=\ln(q), \mathrm{d}t=-\frac{1}{q}\mathrm{d}q\\
=&\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(|x|)-\text{li}\left(q^{x}\right)}{q^x(1+q)}\mathrm{d}q\\
=&\frac{\ln(|x|)}{2}\left(\psi\left(1-\frac{x}{2}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{1-x}{2}\right)\right)-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\text{li}\left(t^x\right)}{t^x}\cdot\frac{1}{1+t}\mathrm{d}t
\end{align*}

The first closed formula is therefore
$$x!_{(\infty)}=\exp\left[\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi}\left(\frac{\ln(|x|)}{2}\left(\psi\left(1-\frac{x}{2}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{1-x}{2}\right)\right)-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\text{li}\left(t^x\right)}{t^x}\cdot\frac{1}{1+t}\mathrm{d}t\right)\right]$$
But the $\psi$ function cannot be calculated in negative integers, so I rewrote it in integral terms, even if multiplying it by $\sin(\pi x)$ the result function has some discontinuities that can be eliminated, so it can be extended
$$x!_{(\infty)}=\exp\left(\frac{\ln(|x|)}{2}\left(1+\int_0^1\frac{\sin\left(x\pi t-\frac{\pi t}{2}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi t}{2}\right)}\mathrm{d}t\right)-\text{sinc}(x)\int_0^1\frac{\text{li}(t^x)}{t^x}\cdot\frac{x}{1+t}\mathrm{d}t\right)$$

Step 2: I integrate by parts the integral involving the function $\text{li}(z)$. To do this I first prove the following formula.
Let $f\in C^1([0,1])$ such that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}f(x)\cdot x<\infty$ and $x>0$
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}\text{li}(t^{x})f'(t)\mathrm{d}t=&\lim_{u\to 1^{-}\atop z\to 0^{+}}\left(\int_{z}^{u}\text{li}(t^x)f'(t)\mathrm{d}t\right)\\
=&\lim_{u\to 1^{-}\atop z\to 0^{+}}\left(\left[\text{li}(t^x)f(t)\right]_{z}^{u}-\int_{z}^{u}\frac{t^{x-1}f(t)}{\ln(t)}\mathrm{d}t\right)\\
=&\lim_{u\to 1^-\atop z\to 0^{+}}\left(\left[\text{li}\left(t^{x}\right)f(t)\right]_{z}^{u}-\int_{z}^{u}\frac{t^{x-1}f(t)-f(u)+f(u)}{\ln(t)}\mathrm{d}t\right)\\
=&\lim_{u\to 1^-\atop z\to 0^{+}}\left(\left[\text{li}\left(t^{x}\right)f(t)\right]_{z}^{u}-\int_{z}^{u}\frac{t^{x-1}f(t)-f(u)}{\ln(t)}\mathrm{d}t-\int_{z}^{u}\frac{f(u)}{\ln(t)}\mathrm{d}t\right)\\
=&\lim_{u\to 1^-\atop z\to 0^{+}}\left(\text{li}\left(u^{x}\right)f(u)-\text{li}(z)f(z)-\int_{z}^{u}\frac{t^{x-1}f(t)-f(u)}{\ln(t)}\mathrm{d}t-\int_{z}^{u}\frac{f(u)}{\ln(t)}\mathrm{d}t\right)\\
=&\lim_{u\to 1^-}\left(\text{li}\left(u^{x}\right)f(u)-\int_{0}^{u}\frac{t^{x-1}f(t)-f(u)}{\ln(t)}\mathrm{d}t-f(u)\text{li}(u)\right)\\
=&\lim_{u\to 1^-}\left(f(u)\left[\text{li}\left(u^{x}\right)-\text{li}(u)\right]-\int_{0}^{u}\frac{t^{x-1}f(t)-f(u)}{\ln(t)}\mathrm{d}t\right)\\
=&f(1)\ln(x)-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^{x-1}f(t)-f(1)}{\ln(t)}\mathrm{d}t
\end{align*}
so
$$\begin{array}{|c|}\hline
\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\text{li}(t^{x})f'(t)\mathrm{d}t=f(1)\ln(x)-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^{x-1}f(t)-f(1)}{\ln(t)}\mathrm{d}t\\\hline
\end{array}$$
Step 2.1: I use this identity in the formula and I obtain
$$x!_{(\infty)}=\left|x\right|\exp\left(\text{sinc}(x)\int_{0}^{1}\frac{_{2}F_{1}\left(\left.{1,x\atop x+1}\right|-1\right)-\frac{1}{t}\ _{2}F_{1}\left(\left.{1,x\atop x+1}\right|-\frac{1}{t}\right)}{\ln\left(t\right)}\mathrm{d}t\right)\qquad x>0$$
Where ${}_{2}F_1\left(\left.{a_1,a_2\atop b_1}\right|z\right)$ is the hypergeometric function.


Question:
I need to write the function
$$\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{t}\cdot\ _{2}F_{1}\left(\left.{1,x\atop x+1}\right|-\frac{1}{t}\right)$$
as an integral, for $t\in(0,1]$ since $\sin(\pi x)$ eliminates the singularities of the hypergeometric function.
I used this integral to define the hypergeometric function
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{s^{x-1}}{s+t}\mathrm{d}s=\frac{1}{tx}\cdot\ _{2}F_{1}\left(\left.{1,x\atop x+1}\right|-\frac{1}{t}\right)\qquad x>0,\text{for }t\in(0,1]$$

Example with $t=0$ and $t=1$
For $t\to 0$ and $t=1$ I have
$$\begin{array}{|lr|}\hline
\displaystyle\underbrace{\sin(\pi x)\int_0^1 s^{x-2}\mathrm{d}s}_{\text{for }x>1}=\underbrace{-\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos((x-1)s)\mathrm{d}s}_{\text{for }x\in\mathbb{R}}&\text{for }t\to 0\\
&\\
\displaystyle\underbrace{\sin(\pi x)\int_0^1\frac{s^{x-1}}{s+1}\mathrm{d}s}_{\text{for }x>0}=\underbrace{\frac{\pi}{2}-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin\left(\left(2x-1\right)s\right)}{\sin\left(s\right)}\mathrm{d}s}_{\text{for }x\in\mathbb{R}}&\text{for }t=1\\\hline
\end{array} $$
And I need
$$\underbrace{\sin(\pi x)\int_0^1\frac{s^{x-1}}{s+t}\mathrm{d}s}_{x>0}=\underbrace{\int_I f(s;t,x)\mathrm{d}s}_{\text{for }x\in\mathbb{R}}\quad \text{for }t\in(0,1]$$

Observations

In general it can be added outside the integral, a constant or a function can also appear, as long as it is $C^{\infty}$ (for example, for $t=1$, $\frac{\pi}{2}$ was added).

I believe that in the simplification a $\ln(|x|)$ can emerge which is then canceled with the $|x|$ out of the exponential (since $x!_{(\infty)}\in C^{\infty}$ it seems natural to try to cancel that absolute value, which is a piecewise function)

I found this formula on Wolfram where ${}_2F_1$ appearts with a complex exponential



My work
Let
$$P(x):=\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{tx}\cdot\ _{2}F_{1}\left(\left.{1,x\atop x+1}\right|-\frac{1}{t}\right)$$
For $N\in\mathbb{N}$
$$P_N(x)=\frac{\sin\left(\pi x\right)}{t}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{N}\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{t}\right)^{n}}{x+n}-\left(-\frac{1}{t}\right)^{N}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{s^{x+N}}{s+t}\mathrm{d}s\right)\qquad x>-N-1$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to -n}P(x)=\pi t^{n-1}\qquad n\in\mathbb{N}$$
an other expression for $P_N(x)$ is
$$P_N(x)=\pi\left(\sum_{n=0}^{N}\frac{\binom{n}{-x}}{(t+1)^{n+1}}+(N+1) \cdot\binom{N}{-x}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{s^{x+N}}{(s+t)^{N+2}}\mathrm{d}s\right)\qquad x>-N-1$$
This form allows direct calculation even for $t=0$ (in that case $x>1$)

Image

For $t=0.9$ the red function is
$$\frac{1}{t}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{N}\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{t}\right)^{n}}{x+n}-\left(-\frac{1}{t}\right)^{N}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{s^{x+N}}{s+t}ds\right)$$
The green one is $P(x)$
Desmos link
This is a link to a graph in desmos to see the function
